# Typescript assigns wrong types to variables (using fs modules)

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, fs

`fs.promises.readFile(filePath, {encoding: "utf8"))` returns `any` while it should return `string`.

If I hover over `readFile` it shows me this:[image]

ts file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function doSomething():Promise<Array<string>> {
    const fileText = await fs.promises.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "testFile"), {encoding: "utf8"});
    const rows = fileText.split(/\n|\r\n|\r/);
    const splitRows = rows.map(value => value.split('\t'));
    return splitRows;
}
```

testFile contents:

```
columnA1    columnB1
columnA2    columnB2
```

The compiler should throw an error because doSomething returns `Promise<Array<Array<string>>>` and not `Promise<Array<string>>`.

If I change the first line in the function to:

```
const fileText:string = await fs.promises.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "testFile"), {encoding: "utf8"});
```

The compiler behaves as it should be.

I do not understand why it doesn't recognize `fileText` as a string.

And even if fileText isn't a string it should know that split returns an array right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `require`, you're importing `fs` and `path` untyped. (If you hover over either of them it should show `any`.) If you use the `import` syntax, the compiler will behave as you expect:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

async function doSomething():Promise<Array<string>> {
    const fileText = await fs.promises.readFile(path.join('__dirname', "testFile"), {encoding: "utf8"});
    const rows = fileText.split(/\n|\r\n|\r/);
    const splitRows = rows.map(value => value.split('\t'));
    return splitRows;
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wGbo1CI4DkWBA3ALABQoksiK6YyMAFprvgYy6ZZWgJ4A7AMaYAriJjAIguABMIAZTwBTFsEEBzABQBKAFwAFdsFQqAPAEEoUZP3OoYUDZoB8ruAG9KcX3GEyjpjAADYqACoqAB7wALwoAO7IwPBYAHRgJmaoaVAqyHIAYqEq2lzMaQBWEBraBAD69XLAUILIICoEADRwAEQwKo7FYb26PZ4qIhDNWvp9YjAYABy9AL665BR+-oHwuAno8RglkTFpqGAhKdoA9AA6ggA+d1APz1A3Gz5+AYJBF1cYAAlCAHODxfY5EDIMDaABuyBCYhU4I8CKRKnOl2uBDuMAIui+Wz8eRgYlacABKRBB02qyAA)

Comment: Thanks so much! Is their any reason for this? I never used ES modules in node.js

Comment: Happy to help :-) The type definitions in `@types/node` declare the return type of `require` to be an object with `any` properties. You can use also use the TypeScript `import fs = require('fs')` syntax for typed imports, but usually es6 imports will do just fine. For more information on importing/exporting, check out https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html